# BUNIFU.net for Visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i would like to know is Bunifu.net compatible with visual studio 2008?
because after i downloaded bunifu.dll when i import it into my toolbox an error occur that says "bunifu.dll is not a .NET module"

Comment: Would it be so much compatible with VS as it would with the .NET framework version...? In that regard, then if you're using the latest VS 2008 can use (3.5 from the top of my head), then it's incompatible.

Comment: @AlexM. even my vs2008 use 3.5 .net framework it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Bunifu is not compatible with .net framework 3.5. It require .net framework 4 or above